# Android and weight

Tags: android

Why does the following code only display two colors and not three? How would one fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="6"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Using `android:layout_weight` without specifying `android:layout_height="0dp"` is not going to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `layout_height` in each of the `LinearLayout`s to be 0:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Any other height gets in the way of Android's calculations for how much space to give to each layout based on the weights.

[image]